# converting string date into the date object and also the year is also stored as YYYY

Tags: java

I am reading an excel value that is it is of date which is of string type and i am converting it in date type to store the date in format of dd/MM/YYYY so below is the way i am doing it

```
private static final SimpleDateFormat outputDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

String dealDateString = cell.getStringCellValue(); // inside this deal date is stored as 05/07/13 
if (dealDateString != null) {
    java.util.Date  dealDate = convertStringToDate(dealDateString);
    String dd = outputDate.format(dealDate); // ----> now the date is stored inside dd string as DD/MM/YYYY as 05/07/2013 
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.UK);
    java.util.Date date = format.parse(dd); //--> but inside date object the year is stored as 13 that is year is stored as YY
}
```

below is the custom method i have designed that will take string and convert it into date object

```
public java.util.Date convertStringToDate(String stringValue) {
    String[] formatStrings = { "dd/MM/yyyy", "dd-MMM-yyyy" ,"dd/MM/YY" , "dd-MM-YY"};

    for (String formatString : formatStrings) {
        try {
            return new SimpleDateFormat(formatString).parse(stringValue);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            logger.warn("##$$$$$### Error in invoice inside convertStringToDate method : ##$$$$$$#### "
                        + ErrorUtility.getStackTraceForException(e));

        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

now the date is converted into java date object but the year is deducted lets say if the year is 2014 then
    year is stored as 14 , please advise how can i store the year as 2014 the main concern is that year is stored as two digits only i want to store it as YYYY

```
folks please advise
```

Comment: Please can you give us a ex-. of input and outputdo you have

Comment: @Abdelhak wel the input string is 06/20/13 and it should be stored inside date object but the year should be stored as 2013

Answer (score 2):

Try to  write this line:

```
String[] formatStrings = { "dd/MM/yyyy", "dd-MMM-yyyy" ,"dd/MM/YY" , "dd-MM-YY"};
```

Like this:

```
 String[] formatStrings = { "dd/MM/yyyy", "dd-MMM-yyyy" ,"dd/MM/yy" , "dd-MM-yy"};
```

Comment: YY being a two digit "week year".

Comment: no that does not work please year is still coming as YY that is 14 i want to achieve 2014 please

Comment: @tgfghfhhghg You are not understanding: Uppercase `Y` has a different meaning than lowercase `y`. Please re-read the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the format.....

When you use **"dd/MM/yyyy"** as fomat, 05/07/13 is traeted as **05/07/0013** and not **05/07/2013** .

Reference from Java [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

> For parsing with the abbreviated year pattern ("y" or "yy"), SimpleDateFormat must interpret the abbreviated year relative to some century. It does this by adjusting dates to be within 80 years before and 20 years after the time the SimpleDateFormat instance is created. For example, using a pattern of "MM/dd/yy" and a SimpleDateFormat instance created on Jan 1, 1997, the string "01/11/12" would be interpreted as Jan 11, 2012 while the string "05/04/64" would be interpreted as May 4, 1964. During parsing, only strings consisting of exactly two digits, as defined by Character.isDigit(char), will be parsed into the default century. Any other numeric string, such as a one digit string, a three or more digit string, or a two digit string that isn't all digits (for example, "-1"), is interpreted literally. So "01/02/3" or "01/02/003" are parsed, using the same pattern, as Jan 2, 3 AD. Likewise, "01/02/-3" is parsed as Jan 2, 4 BC.

Use

dd/MM/yy as format instead of dd/MM/yyyy.It will solve your issue.

```
String[] formatStrings = { "dd/MM/yy", "dd-MMM-yy" ,"dd/MM/yy" , "dd-MM-yy"};
```

Answer (score 0):

## Incorrect Parsing Pattern

[The Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34102790/642706) by Abdelhak is correct: You are defining incorrect formatting pattern. The uppercase `Y` has a different meaning than lowercase `y`.

## java.time

You are using the old date-time classes from the early years of Java. These classes have proven to be troublesome, flawed in design and implementation. Avoid them (java.util.Date/.Calendar & java.text.SimpleTextFormat).

Instead use the java.time framework built into Java 8 and later.

The java.time classes include [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) to represent a date-only value with no time-of-day.

```
// If used repeatedly many times, keep this List around for re-use rather instantiating over and over.
List<DateTimeFormatter> formatters = new ArrayList<>(4);
formatters.add( DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yy") );
formatters.add( DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yy") );
formatters.add( DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy") );
formatters.add( DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy") );

LocalDate localDate = null;  // Using null as a flag for success/failure.
for( DateTimeFormatter formatter : formatters ) {
    try {
        localDate = LocalDate.parse( input , formatter );
    } catch ( DateTimeParseException e ) {
        // Ignore this exception, as we expect some.
    }
}
if( null == localDate ) {
    // … handle failure to parse. Must be unexpected input.
} else {
    // … handle success. You now have a LocalDate object.
    String output = localDate.toString(); // Generates a String in ISO 8601 format.
    String outputInFormatNotRecommended = localDate.format( formatters.get( 0 ) );
}
```

If your goal is to serialize the date value as a String, I strongly suggest you use the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format (YYYY-MM-DD). This format is easily recognizable by most any culture, is easy to read, and sorts alphabetically as chronologically.